# htaccess: rewrite .php to .html with exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a working .htaccess file that changes .php to .html. How can I modify this so that index.php stays a .php file extension?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Your code makes both the `.html` and the `.php` available for use. So index.php will still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
```